# Find history of rollbacks on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, rollback

Is there a way to find the history of any and all rollbacks that happened on a SQL Server database? Specifically, I would like to know the time and the user. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`? Not very easily. You could use `DBCC LOG` or `fn_dblog()` to find rollbacks that have happened in the active transaction log. Getting the same information from old log backups requires `fn_dump_dblog()`.

```
SELECT
    l.name,
    r.*
FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) b
        ON r.[Transaction ID] = b.[Transaction ID]
        AND b.Operation = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.server_principals l
        ON b.[Transaction SID] = l.sid
WHERE r.Operation = 'LOP_ABORT_XACT'
```

A better option would be to configure either a trace or extended event session to record rollbacks, though this would only help you going forward.